Closed XML - Excel - VB,Net
I'm pretty new to the field, I have been trying to use ClosedXML to create and modify Excel files automatically.
But this doesn't seem to be working. I'm basically trying to copy data from 2 files into a third one (a new file) with this code:
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement
Imports ClosedXML
Imports ClosedXML.Excel
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

        Dim wb1 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook("C:\Users\oxy\Downloads\Test\Test.xlsx")
        Dim ws As IXLWorksheet = wb1.AddWorksheet
        wb1.SaveAs("C:\Users\oxy\Downloads\Test\Test2.xlsx")

        Dim wb2 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim ws2 As IXLWorksheet = wb2.AddWorksheet
        ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertData(ws2.Columns("A:G"))

        wb1.SaveAs("C:\Users\oxy\Downloads\Test\Test2.xlsx")

        Dim wb3 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim ws3 As IXLWorksheet = wb3.AddWorksheet
        ws.Cell(1, 6).InsertData(ws3.Columns("A:N"))
        wb1.SaveAs("C:\Users\oxy\Downloads\Test\Test2.xlsx")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel | *.xls; *.xlsx"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "Excel | *.xls; *.xlsx"
        OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog()
        TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog2.FileName

    End Sub
End Class

I thought of the possibility of having mistakes in either the way I tried to copy columns from a file to another OR the way of selecting a range of columns might not be correct.
I tried some different ways but it doesn't seem to be the problem
this is my first ever post in this community, so sorry for any mistakes, thank you in advance.

You may want to clarify "it's not working".

No new file is made or saved on the " Test " folder , the VStudio shows an error when i run the app saying  ((" Unhandled exception has occurred in your application , IF you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue , if you click quit , the application will close immediately ( empty extension is not
supported )) and basically nothing happens when i continue and try to browse the 2 excel files and click the button4 @iakobski

"Test" is a folder? In that case you've not given your new file a name. You can't create a file the same name as an existing directory name. Run the program in the debugger and it will stop when the exception is thrown, you'll then have some idea why.

... Well yes i missed that out it was supposed to be ".SaveAs" to begin with , any way i adjusted the code and ran it in the debugger but still , the only thing changes now that it makes em an empty file "Test2.xlsx" and when i debug the process memory rocket to 89 and nothing happens

"Nothing happens" is not quite true is it? Something happens, you get an empty workbook saved in a file. Neither have you told us what you're expecting to happen. I'm guessing you want to copy data from worksheets ws2 and ws3 into a single new worksheet in file Test2. But there's no data in ws2 and ws3 because you've just created them.

As you've tagged this question C# that's what I'll answer in, you'll have to convert it to VB yourself.
You have two remaining problems at the time of writing:

You are trying to copy from new (empty) worksheets
InsertData() cannot take a Columns object. It appears to because it takes an Enumerable, and Columns is Enumerable, but Enumerating it does not return the data in the cells. So once you've sorted problem 1, you'll just get nonsense in your created file.

I think this does what you're trying to do, though I'll caveat that I'm guessing as you've not actually told us more than "I want to copy data"
private void Button4_Click( /* args */)
{
    var wb1 = new XLWorkbook(@"C:\Users\oxy\Downloads\Test\Test.xlsx");
    var ws = wb1.AddWorksheet();
    
    var wb2 = new XLWorkbook(TextBox1.Text);
    var ws2 = wb2.Worksheet(1);// assume you want the first
    ws2.Range("A:G").CopyTo(ws.Cell("A1"));

    // repeat for file 2
    
    wb1.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\oxy\Downloads\Test\Test2.xlsx");
}


You're correct , i was trying to copy the Data from the first worksheet in wb1  ( ws1) and 1st worksheet in (ws2) , instead i was making a new worksheet in both workbooks and copying the data (null) from these new worksheets to the new single worksheet file .
though i made some coding mistake in copying the data ( and yes , i did a mistake here as well as you explained , it works , You're a hero
thank you so much for your time . )

@RodwanAlburie if this works, feel free to mark this as the accepted answer.
